# Deployment of database on client's computer

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

I have developed a Windows application in .NET which uses a SQL Server database to store, retrieve and manipulate data and tables through sql queries.

Now I want to know when I would deliver its executable (.exe) file to client then in which form I have to deliver that database so that the application can connect to database.

Should I install complete SQL Server on client's computer?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things, basically:

- require your clients to have a SQL Server installed already - then it's their job and responsability to make sure they have a SQL Server ready for your app.

or

- you could include the free to use **SQL Server Express** with your application and send that along with your installation, so that they could install that.

In both cases, you need some way to deliver your database:

- send along a colletcion of SQL scripts to create the database, create the necessary tables and views and stored procedures, and possibly also fill in some static lookup data. For this option, I personally would use a tool like Red-Gate [SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Packager/index.htm) to package up all my SQL scripts into a .NET assembly or executable

or

- deliver a prepared SQL Server .mdf/.ldf file to just attach to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server Express Edition. Its a somewhat limited but free Edition of the sql server you can use for that.